# Get Comments On a Photo Using Its Photo ID in GData object-c client(Picasa)

Tags: objective-c, ios, photo, gdata, picasa

I am currently working on a an iOS app that needs to get a Picasa image's comments using the photoID of the picture. However there is no mentions of comments on the developer guide that google provides and I am also a beginner on working with GData. Can Someone Please Help Me get an Image using its photo ID, then get the comments for it. Any Help Would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://apigee.com/console/picasa
Checkout this online tool to list all api for picasa.
I think it will be lot helpful to you